# Change Shell Font via Command

Tags: bash, debian, terminal, xfce, fonts

I play a lot of Nethack and I suspect that I'm not alone in preferring a larger font for it than I normally use for my terminal. I tend to use 12 for normal terminal stuff (vim or whatever) and 16+ for Nethack. Normally I just change the font in my preferences but I'm getting the urge to automate this process. I want to create a script or an alias or something that will change the font size and launch nethack with a single command. Can it be done?

Edit:

OS: Debian
DE: Xfce
Shell: Bash

Comment: We cannot know if it can be done if we do not know details about what is being used.

Comment: Updated it with my distro, shell, and desktop environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the terminal emulator you are using.

For instance, xfce4-terminal stores its configuration in `${XDG_CONFIG_DIRS}/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc` and `${XDG_CONFIG_DIRS}/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm`. When starting a new instance, it also let you execute a given command with the `-x`/`--execute` and `-e`/`--command` options. With features like these it's easy to create a function/script to automatize what you want.

Example:

```
run-nano() {
  sed -Ei 's/^(FontName=Noto Mono )9$/\112/g' <config-file>
  nano
  sed -Ei 's/^(FontName=Noto Mono )12$/\19/g' <config-file>
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Works like a charm. I used an alias instead of a function but now I'm lauching nethack and increasing the font in one command. And I learned about sed! Thanks kind stranger.